# Python -- Split string into list through regex list

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to convert a single string to a list of strings based upon a list of corresponding RegEx values.

My code currently looks like this:

```
def regexSplit(s, regexList):
    retList = [""]*len(regexList)

    i = 0
    for e in enumerate(regexList):
        retList[i] = regex.search(regexList[i], s)
        s = s.split(retList[i], 1)[1]

        i += 1

    return retList
```

When attempting to run the code, however, I am getting the error:

```
in regexSplit
    s = s.split(retList[i], 1)[1]
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

#### Goal Example:

I'm trying to get it so that passing values such that if

```
s = "|Y4000|,03/02/2015,2000,||,|REDLANDS|,|CA|,|92375|"
```

and

```
regexList = ['[\w\d]{5}', '[0,1][1-9][/][0-3][0-9][/][\d]{4}', '[-]?[\d]*', '[^|]{0,40}', '[\w\s]{0,30}', '[\w]{2}', '[\d]{0,5}']
```

the returned list would be:

```
["Y4000", "03/02/2015", "2000", "", "REDLANDS", "CA", "92375"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might be better off replacing any split chars with a `,` and then just splitting on `,` It feels like that's more close to what you want to do.

Comment: The CSV-ish text file that I'm working with makes it difficult to use such reasonable approaches (some value fields contain `,` and `"` and other such complications...)

Comment: Yes, so we simply do a for loop over all replacements so `for r in replacements: s.replace(r,',')` that will replace all dividers with commas, then we split on the commas.

Comment: I think str.translate and split would be a lot simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to achieve, split is not the right function. Write one regex and create a subexpression for each of the strings you want to parse. Start with something like `([\w\d]{5}).*?([,][0,1][1-9][/][0-3][0-9][/][\d]{4}).*?` ... and so forth.

Then you can use

```
p = re.compile('<your regex>')
m = p.match('ab')
retTuple = m.group(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

and you can use the resulting Tuple just like a list (except that it is immutable).